# How to install other dependent packages through apt during the installation of the deb package

Tags: apt, software-installation, dpkg, dependencies, deb

I try to make a deb installation package by myself, and this deb package needs to install some dependent packages, but when I execute the command "apt install" in the preinst script, I will report this error: error processing archive testDeb_1.0.0_i386.deb (--install):nd. It is held by process 28 (dpkg)

How can I install other dependent packages during the deb process?

Comment: You don't install packages within the maintainer scripts. You declare the dependencies in the control file and provide the dependencies in your repo or PPA.

Comment: How to provide dependencies in the repo or PPA, I am building a deb package for the first time, if there is a link to deal with dependencies, please provide it, thank you very much